# How to upload code to Jupyter so that other people can use the function I have created but cant see how the function works?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've created a very specialized function in python which I would like to make available for others in my community to use by hyperlink to Jupyter and then just typing the function's name and filling in the arguments, but I don't want the people seeing how it was coded or how it works.
Is this possible?

thank you